# How do I turn my query result into a link?

Tags: php, html

I am returning data from three columns and displayed it with:

```
echo "<p><h3><span class='tyler'>".$results['COL 2']."</span></h3>".$results['COL 4'].$results['COL 3']."</p>";
```

This works fine. `COL 4` is an actual URL and I am trying to put it in an anchor tag with `COL 3` as the anchor text:

```
echo "<p><h3><span class='tyler'>".$results['COL 2']."</span></h3>""<a href=".$results['COL 4']"/>".$results['COL 3']."</a></p>";
```

I am trying to use this code but it doesn't work. My assumption is that the problem has something to do with the back to back quotes after the closing `h3` tag. How would I go about making this work?

Comment: What is the result, what do you see in your browser when you try this? We can't possibly know what is in those "COL 2" and so on. Also, your concatenation is invalid, it's supposed to be echo "<p><h3><span class='tyler'>".$results['COL 2']."</span></h3>""<a href=".$results['COL 4']."/>".$results['COL 3']."</a></p>";

Comment: When you say 'it doesn't work', what actual output are you seeing? Refer to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `$results['COL 4']"/>"` should be `$results['COL 4'].">"`

Comment: I see nothing in my browser. I hit search and it moves to the search page and displays nothing. I tried what you suggested Eihawz and it didn't work either.

Comment: Do you see error messages in your log? Does your html source show anything? What are you hitting when you hit 'search'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can get confusing to build large strings that are output to HTML. This is what you have:

```
echo "<p><h3><span class='tyler'>"
     .$results['COL 2']
     ."</span></h3>""<a href=".$results['COL 4']"/>"
     .$results['COL 3']
     ."</a></p>";
```

I've broken it up to more clearly reference what is going on. In the third line (starting with the close-`span` tag), you have two double quotes right next to each other. Further on, you have quotes opening the close-slash part of the tag, but not a string concatenation operator (`.`). Finally, you are confusing double and single quotes. You want:

```
."</span></h3><a href='".$results['COL 4']."'/>"
```

But a better way of doing this would be to split out your components:

```
$title = $results['COL 2'];
$href = $results['COL 4'];
$anchor_text = $results['COL 4'];
// Here you can add debugging statements to ensure you have the right values.

$paragraph = "<p><h3><span class='tyler'>%s</span></h3><a href='%s'>%s</a></p>"
echo sprintf($paragraph, $title, $href, $anchor_text);
```

This method uses [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to 'slot in' the strings you want. It allows you to be more clear about building the html, without worrying about what the specific 'dynamic' values are. There are, of course, many other ways of doing this sort of 'templating'.

## An Aside on String Building in PHP

This line of code assigns a simple string to a variable in PHP:

```
$message = "Hello world!";
```

This line of code 'concatenates' three strings using the concatenation operator (which is a dot: `.`):

```
$html = "<p>".$html."</p>";
```

This line would yield an equivalent result:

```
$html = "<p>Hello world!</p>";
```

This line will yield an error:

```
$bad = "<p>""Hello world!""</p>";
```

The reason it yields an error is because the language will 'tokenize' the code into something like:

```
<variable name> <assign> <string> <string> <string> <end statement>
```

Except that, semantically, three `<string>`s in a row doesn't make sense. It needs an 'operator' between them, like so:

```
<variable name> <assign> <string> <concatenate> <string> <concatenate> <string> <end statement>
```

PHP knows how to 'parse' this string of tokens. It will know to evaluate each string, and then concatenate them together. An intermediate stage becomes this:

```
<variable name> <assign> <string (composed of three previous strings)> <end statement>
```

It knows this because the concatenation operator tells it how to combine those strings.

That brings us back to using the dot/concatenation operator:

```
$html = "<p>Hello world!</p>";
```

Now, HTML markup looks like this:

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/help">SO Help Page</a>
```

And when PHP 'outputs' the final result, all it is doing is 'echo'ing or 'printing' a string to the HTML response. Given that, and given that PHP interprets a double quote as the 'end' of a string, how do you put strings into a variable, so it prints out like the HTML above? This won't work, because PHP doesn't know how to interpret `http://...` in this context:

```
echo "<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/help">SO Help Page</a>";
```

There are a few ways to get around this. You can 'escape' the double quotes:

```
echo "<a href=\"http://www.stackoverflow.com/help\">SO Help Page</a>";
```

By inserting a `\` in the string before the double quote you signal to PHP to *not* end the string token, and to therefore parse the whole thing as a single string.

Alternatively, HTML also accepts single quotes for it's attribute values. So you can do this:

```
echo "<a href='http://www.stackoverflow.com/help'>SO Help Page</a>";
```

Which yields this on the HTML response:

```
<a href='http://www.stackoverflow.com/help'>SO Help Page</a>
```

Regardless of which way you go, you have to remember that the PHP code does not magically know that you're building an HTML page: it is simply constructing and printing strings to the HTML response. You have to tell it when to ignore parts of the string.

My point above is that for long enough PHP scripts, this can become confusing. So breaking down the strings into manageable chunks, so you can see what you're inserting and where things (like quotes, open and close tags, etc.) are makes your life easier.

Comment: What you said was way over my head. This is my first php attempt. All I am trying to do is create a two page site. A home search page and a second page that displays the results. I tried what you had suggested at the top and it didn't work. I am unsure on where to add the code where we split it up. Would that go right after the while loop?

Comment: @TylerJensen Added some explanation. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: It worked! It was irritating me yesterday so I started work on something else. I came back this morning to give it another go and it started working. Thank you for the help.